# JSON complex format

Tags: php, mysql, json

First of all, I have to admit that I am pretty bad at handling JSON. I need to ask for some help on a problem that is bothering me for around two week. So, I am trying to create a basic Web Service for an iOS/Android application. I am following the instructions given by the App developer to correctly create the API. Everything seemed pretty easy until I reached the point I had to create the getContents.php.
This is my PHP code for fetching and echoing the data:

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json;');
$article_id = $_GET["ArticleID"];


$link = mysql_connect('localhost','bridgeapp_user','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('bridgeapp',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');  


mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $link);


if (isset($article_id)) {
    $query = "SELECT description AS `content`, 'http://offercat.com/media/com_jbusinessdirectory/pictures'+logoLocation AS `images` FROM vrfmp_jbusinessdirectory_companies WHERE id = '".$article_id. "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

}

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
//    $rows = str_replace("name", "title", "$rows");
}

echo json_encode($rows);

@mysql_close($link);
```

What I get from that code is this:

```
[{"content":"<p>asdasdasd<\/p>","images":"0"}]
```

And what I would like to get looks something like this:

```
{
"content": "<p><img src=\"http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_screenshots.png\" alt=\"DigiDiet Screenshots\" width=\"100%\"/></p><p>Το <a href=\"http://www.digidiet.gr\" target=\"_blank\">DigiDiet</a> ήρθε για να σας βοηθήσει στην προσπάθειά σας για μια ισορροπημένη διατροφή που θα οδηγήσει στην απώλεια βάρους, με την καθοδήγηση εξειδικευμένων επιστημονικών συνεργατών.</p><p>Πρόκειται για μια πλατφόρμα που αναπτύχθηκε και εξελίσσεται συνεχώς από τις <a href=\"http://www.acsoft.gr\">ACSoft</a>, <a href=\"http://www.cwi.gr\" target=\"_blank\">CWI</a> και <a href=\"http://www.digiapps.gr\" target=\"_blank\">DigiApps</a>, εταιρείες που δραστηριοποιούνται στο χώρο της τεχνολογίας και της ανάπτυξης λογισμικού.</p><p>Απευθύνεται σε όσους:</p><p><ul><li>Βρίσκονται σε διαδικασία απώλειας βάρους</li><li>Δυσκολεύονται να τηρήσουν ένα σωστό διαιτολόγιο</li><li>Έχουν μεταβλητά ωράρια εργασίας και απαιτητικές επαγγελματικές υποχρεώσεις που επηρεάζουν τη σωστή διατροφή</li><li>Ξεχνούν να καταναλώσουν το σωστό γεύμα την κατάλληλη ώρα</li><li>Αθλούνται συστηματικά και χρειάζονται συνεχή παρακολούθηση και καθοδήγηση στα πλαίσια της καθημερινής διατροφής τους</li><li>Αναρρώνουν από κάποιο πρόβλημα υγείας και πρέπει να τηρήσουν συγκεκριμένο διαιτολόγιο, με την καθοδήγηση κάποιου εξειδικευμένου ιατρού</li></ul></p><p>Η εφαρμογή δημιουργήθηκε από την <a href=\"http://www.acsoft.gr\">ACSoft</a> και μπορείτε να την κατεβάσετε <strong>ΔΩΡΕΑΝ</strong> στο κινητό σας από το Apple AppStore.</p><p>Σύντομα θα είναι διαθέσιμη και η αντίστοιχη έκδοση για το Android στο Google PlayStore.</p><p><a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/gr/app/digidiet/id761559243?mt=8&uo=4\" style=\"margin-right:10px;\" target=\"_blank\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/AppStore.png\" /></a></p>",
"social_link": "http://www.acsoft.gr/index.php/blog/apps/13-digidiet-app",
"images": [
    "http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_photo1.png",
    "http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_photo2.png",
    "http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_photo3.png",
    "http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_photo4.png",
    "http://toolbox.acsoft.gr/acblog/images/digidiet/digidiet_photo5.png"
]}
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve that ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You cannot select `social_link` from db

Comment: can you show schema of `vrfmp_jbusinessdirectory_companies`

Comment: And this is wrong, what's that url?  `"SELECT description AS content, 'http://offercat.com/media/com_jbusinessdirectory/pictures'+logoLocation AS images`

Comment: Your queries are open for **sql injections**, I would recommend to not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API but rather `mysqli` or `PDO` and to use `prepared statements`.

Comment: It is my understanding that is has a ton of issues I should fix. Thanks for your pieces of advice. It would be great if I had some advice on the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$images[]=$r['images'];


}
$social="some content here";

$content="some content here ";

$rows=array("content"=>$content,"social_link"=>$social,"images"=>$images);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you very much !